# MySQL Join Query to get the sum of items in a cart table from products coming from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

This is an extention to my previous problem, which happen to be because the item was in another table...

i have 4 tables:

**cart**

```
+------------+----------+------------+---------+
| customerid | itemcode | cartactive |  type   |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+
|       9916 | X        | Yes        | Package |
|       9916 | Y        | Yes        | Product |
+------------+----------+------------+---------+
```

**products**

```
+-------------+------------+
| ProductCode | shipWeight |
+-------------+------------+
| Y           |          1 |
| ITEM1       |          1 |
| ITEM2       |          2 |
| ITEM3       |          1 |
+-------------+------------+
```

**package**

```
+-------------+
| PackageCode |
+-------------+
| X           |
+-------------+
```

**PackageItems**

```
+-------------+-------------+
| PackageCode | ProductCode |
+-------------+-------------+
| X           | ITEM1       |
| X           | ITEM2       |
| X           | ITEM3       |
+-------------+-------------+
```

So basically but not easily im trying to get the SUM of all items in the cart which we see here should be 5.

Here is the query i wrote that is returning *Not unique table/alias: 'products'*:

```
Select 
SUM(products.shipWeight) as totalweight 
FROM 
cart 
Left JOIN products  ON products.ProductCode = cart.itemCode
LEFT JOIN packageitems d on cart.itemCode = packageitems.PackageCode
LEFT JOIN products on d.ItemCode = products.ProductCode
 WHERE 
cart.customerId= '9916' AND 
cart.cartActive = 'Yes'
```

I think i some how have to find the sum of all regular products first then find all items in the package and tally their shipping cost and add them together. I'm a little new to this. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do `X` Package Code appear on `products` Table? Because if that is that case will generate duplicated because will join with `products` and `package`

Comment: X is separate from products. Only package items are in products.

Comment: What is the `package` table for? The query doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just join using `OR`

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ac3561/4)**

I didnt include the `SUM` so you can see the result.

```
SELECT c.`itemcode`, pi.`ProductCode`, p.`ProductCode`, p.`shipWeight`
FROM cart c
LEFT JOIN PackageItems pi
       ON c.`itemcode` = pi.`PackageCode`
LEFT JOIN products p
       ON p.`ProductCode` = c.`itemcode`
       OR p.`ProductCode` = pi.ProductCode 
WHERE c.`customerid`= '9916' AND 
c.`cartactive` = 'Yes'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you're joining with the `products` table twice, you need to use aliases to distinguish which instance should be used.

```
Select 
    SUM(p2.shipWeight) as totalweight 
FROM cart 
Left JOIN products AS p1 ON p1.ProductCode = cart.itemCode
LEFT JOIN packageitems d on cart.itemCode = d.PackageCode
LEFT JOIN products AS p2 on d.ProductCode = p2.ProductCode
WHERE 
    cart.customerId= '9916' AND 
    cart.cartActive = 'Yes'
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c46c3/2)

There were other errors in the SQL in the question:

1. When you assign the alias `d` to `packageitems`, you can't use `packageitems.PackageCode` in the `ON` clause, it has to be `d.PackageCode`.
2. There's no `itemCode` in `packageitems`, so `d.itemCode` is wrong, it should be `d.ProductCode`.

Comment: I'm not sure this is right, the result is only `4`, not `5`. It's just adding `ITEM1`, `ITEM2`, and `ITEM3`, not `Y`.

Comment: OP say  `SUM() =5` but you can use my fiddle to test it

Comment: yeah i got 5 as well! Awsome job

Comment: @NeoSketo I'm not sure why you're getting 5 when I get 4.

Comment: @Barmar ah the package in my real time project had more items in it. i think its not calculating the regular product...

Answer (score 0):

Rename the tables and use alias in join on condition.

```
Select SUM(prod2.shipWeight) as totalweight
FROM 
cart
Left JOIN products prod1  ON prod1.ProductCode = cart.itemCode
LEFT JOIN packageitems d on cart.itemCode = d.PackageCode
LEFT JOIN products prod2 on d.ItemCode = prod2.ProductCode
WHERE 
cart.customerId= '9916' AND 
cart.cartActive = 'Yes'
```

Comment: LEFT JOIN packageitems d on cart.itemCode = d.PackageCode in the accept answer was still LEFT JOIN packageitems d on cart.itemCode = packageitems.PackageCode